# Export files from search with file share content source

Tags: search, file, share, copy

I'm new to SharePoint and we're trying to provide users with the ability to search a file share and copy files, that are found, though the interface into another location network share.  Is this possible?

Comment: when you say File Share, presumably you mean a Document Library.  Is your question that you wish to copy files from one Document Library to another?  Or do you wish to copy from Doc Library to another location outside of Sharepoint?  BTW - you might find 'map network drive' is useful, if you are used to working in a file server.  Though working in this fashion you would miss out on lots of cool Sharepoint stuff like views, filters and all the meta-data fields that can assist the user in SP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  We have a search that has a Network share as the Content Source.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this out of the box but you could add some elements to the UI to make it easier, like a link to open the file share in explorer. Use JavaScript to create a `file://` link. Then you can decide how to open the destination location. From their the user could drag and drop.

I am sure if you have JavaScript skills you could develop a menu option for performing the copy in place in the search result.